# gspread writing data on google spreadsheet gives error on live database

Tags: python, odoo, gspread

I have used the **gspread** for writing the data on Google spreadsheet. Its working fine locally but when I was trying at live server it gives me a following error.

```
File "/home/openerp10/openerp_7.0/addons/spreadsheet_calculate_all/spreadsheet_calculate_all.py", line 53, in insert
a = c.open(title).sheet1
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gspread-0.1.0-py2.7.egg/gspread/client.py", line 130, in open
raise SpreadsheetNotFound
SpreadsheetNotFound
```

The code is as follow,

```
res_user = self.pool.get('res.users')
sale = self.browse(cr,uid,ids)[0]
username = res_user.browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context).gmail_user
passwd = res_user.browse(cr, uid, uid, context=context).gmail_password
title = sale.document
if title and username and passwd:
    try:
        c = gspread.Client(auth=(username,passwd))
        c.login()
        a = c.open(title).sheet1
    except Exception, e:
        raise osv.except_osv(_('User Error!'), _('Please give correct google username,password and document title.'))
```

Please give me any solution on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OMG, Code is run well. The error occurs because of the Name of Spreadsheet mis-match.

I added field in Sale Order which take the char as a name of Spreadsheet.

If the field value and Google Spreadsheet Name is not same than it will gives above error.